# How to add custom renderers to only some specific Layouts?

Tags: android, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Let's say, I wanna change the font of the label. That means that I'll have to write something like that:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(LabelFontRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class LabelFontRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var label = (TextView)Control; // for example
            Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "Roboto-Regular.ttf");  // font name specified here
            label.Typeface = font;
        }
    }
}
```

However, adding that to a project will make all labels render with the specified font. What if I want to make only some, specific labels render with that font?

Maybe a solution is to inherit from Label and add renderer to that inherited class, thus applying it only to the instances of that particular class and therefore applying it only to specified labels. Thus, my question consists of two parts: (1) is the way that I described the correct way and will it work, and if not, (2) what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe a solution is to inherit from Label and add renderer to that inherited class, thus applying it only to the instances of that particular class and therefore applying it only to specified labels.

This is the correct way of doing custom renderers for *your* controls/needs. By exporting the renderer for `Label` type, you're modifying the all the labels in the app.

You have to create a inherited `Label` class in the shared project and define a custom renderer for it. For example:

In shared/portable project:

```
public class MyLabel : Label {}
```

In Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyLabel), typeof(LabelFontRenderer))] 
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class LabelFontRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var label = (TextView)Control; // for example
            Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "Roboto-Regular.ttf");  // font name specified here
            label.Typeface = font;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myLabel = new MyLabel { Text = "Hello" };
```

Comment: sorry, I'm confused. are you saying that the solution I provided is the correct one?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze no, you have to inherit the Label class and use it. I will updated my answer for more clarity :)

Comment: that's what I said, actually. maybe I didn't express myself correctly.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze, LOL, I confused myself. Anyway, I have added the code sample